# Helping or Help?

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund

Could the word "help" be used instead of "helping" in this sentence? Would the meaning be the same either way?

> Money will also go to helping the pink iguana and the Floreana
> tortoise. ([The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2021/may/18/leonardo-dicaprio-pledges-43m-to-restore-the-galapagos-islands))

I think both work since helping is in the future continuous form and is talking about money that will be used in the future and continue for an expected length of time. ***Help*** is a verb that can also be used for the future when used with "will"(Example: He will help...).

I found this issue discussed in [Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-the-words-help-and-helping-in-the-English-language-Arent-they-both-nouns#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CHelp%E2%80%9D%20is%20both%20a%20noun,meaning%20a%20serving%20of%20food.&text=We%20don%27t%20use%20the,we%20use%20%E2%80%9Chelp%E2%80%9D%20instead.).

Comment: That link from quora has answers. Are they not satisfactory for you?

Comment: fev, in this particular context, only *helping* is the right choice.

Comment: "helping" is a gerund here, the object of the preposition "to", not "future continuous"

Answer (score 2):

The following are all correct:

> "The money will **also go toward helping** the orphans"
> "The money will **also help** the orphans"
> "The money will **also be used to help** the orphans"

"go to helping" is strange phrase, but not unheard of.
Usually, people would write, "go **toward** helping"

Answer (score 2):

> Money will also go *to* [**helping** the pink iguana and the Floreana tortoise].

Here **helping** is the only right option and not *help*, and also note that *to* here is not a infinitive marker, but a preposition.

> He went there [*to* **help his friend**].

Here *to* is a infinitive marker and *help* is in its plain form. [*to* **help his friend**] is an infinitive clause. This is a non finite clause.

In your sentence [**helping** the pink iguana and the Floreana tortoise] is a Gerund-Participle clause. This too is a non finite clause.

And by itself a non finite clause is un-tensed. We can't locate the situation in time from the non finite clause by itself. So your assumption that *helping* is in future continuous tense is wrong. It is the verb of the matrix clause - *will* - that actually locates the situation in time.

Comment: If we substitute “toward” for “to” it may be clearer: ‘*the money will go **toward help** iguanas’ vs ‘the money will be **used to help** iguanas’ vs ‘the money will go toward help **for** iguanas’

Comment: @ColleenV did you indicate "the money will go to help iguanas" wrong?

Comment: No, it’s not wrong exactly, because people do say and understand it that way, even though I prefer “toward” over “to”. I’m fine with telling learners to use “helping” and not “help” though.

Comment: Nice to see you after a long while. I am sad that I no longer find mynold company. ELL too needs them a lot. @ColleenV

Answer (score 0):

Q. Could the word "help" be used instead of "helping" in this sentence?

A. I would suggest the meaning would not be the same as the help would then, by definition, not be on-going.

---

> Salesforce GM & chief medical officer as Salesforce, discusses the company's new vaccine cloud technology, and how Salesforce is **helping** to vaccinate more than two billion people around the world by the end of 2021.

The use of helping denotes an ongoing action in this case. Whilst the word help is a one off action.

> *Your donation to Vaccinate Your Family will **help us** to*:
> Raise Public Awareness of the Importance of Timely Vaccinations and their Safety
> Broker Key Partnerships to Strengthen Health Equity in Vulnerable Communities
> Advocate for Policy Change to Improve Access to Timely Vaccinations

In some cases this use can be rather subtle, however the meaning is not quite the same; for example.

> I will be stopping the car at various locations along the road.

*Implies one journey with numerous drop off's/pick up's/breaks*

> The car will stop at various locations along the road.

Implies several short journeys (Stop- Start)

Comment: But does this answer OP's question?

Comment: Q. Could the word "help" be used instead of "helping" in this sentence?
A. I would suggest the meaning would not be the same as the help would then, by definition, not be on-going.

Comment: I believe this is not correct. Consider: "very close to doing something". Here it doesn't imply the "do" is in progress.